# How to fix an error in web scraping Facebook Marketplace with infinite scrolling using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, facebook, web-scraping

My code is scraping housing data from Facebook Marketplace, but I'm facing an issue. Initially, it can only read 24 listings when the page is opened. However, when I try to load more listings by scrolling down the page, my code starts reading all listings from the beginning instead of the 25th listing. How can I resolve this issue?

```
open = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@ class="x3ct3a4"]')
#open it's a list of all clickable housing listings when I open the page

while True:
    for o in open:
        sleep(random.randint(1, 2))

        #Here I read the data that I need 

        close_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, close_xpath)
        close_button.click()
        sleep(random.randint(1, 2))
        #Here I close the listing and go to the next one
        
    #When I read all 24 listings that were in the 'open' list, I then scroll the page down and try to get new listings and then read them

    driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);')
    sleep(random.randint(2, 4)
    open = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, open_xpath)

    #But after the scroll, my code starts reading the same listings that it already read.
```

Here is my output:

```
1
['', '2 Beds 1 Bath Apartment']
['$1,600 / Month']
2
['', '1 Bed 1 Bath Apartment']
['$1,500 / Month']

.
.
.
24
['', '2 Beds 2 Baths Apartment']
['$1,350 / Month']
25
['', '2 Beds 1 Bath Apartment']
['$1,600 / Month']
26
['', '1 Bed 1 Bath Apartment']
['$1,500 / Month']
```

So, after the 24th opened link, code start reading all listings again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a couple of things.

#### Remove elements from the html

At the end of the `for o in open:` loop, delete the current element `o` from the html using javascript.

```
for o in open:
    ...
    driver.execute_script('var element = arguments[0]; element.remove();', o)
```

However, this method may not work: sometimes when you scroll down to load new elements, the page reloads all the previous elements which are then re-added to the html. If this is the case try the next method.

#### Add a counter and loop over the new elements

Define a counter and loops over the elements with index bigger than the counter (i.e. loops over only the new elements). The first time the `while` loop is executed, counter is 0 so the `for` loops over all the elements contained in `open` (`for o in open[0:]:`). At the end of the `for`, `counter` will be equal to 24, so at the second execution of the `while` we will have `for o in open[24:]:` which means that the first 24 elements are now excluded.

```
open = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//div[@ class="x3ct3a4"]')
counter = 0
while True:
    for o in open[counter:]:
        ...
        counter += 1
           
    ...
```